# Variant on the Monty Hall Problem ($4$ Doors, $2$ Prizes)

Tags: probability, statistics, finance, monty-hall

I had the following question as part of a Finance course I'm doing. I don't struggle too much with Monty Hall problems in which there are $3$ doors, but this one with $4$ doors ($2$ with Prizes and $2$ with Goats, NONE empty) I am stumped even after several attempts:

> "Consider a version of the Monty Hall problem where there are $4$ doors. There are goats behind $2$ of the doors and valuable prizes behind the other $2$ doors. The game is played as follows:
>
> - You first choose a door.
> - Before your chosen door is opened Monty Hall opens one of the other $3$ doors and reveals a goat behind that door.
> - He now gives you the opportunity to change your mind and select another door.
> - Your chosen door is now opened and your prize is revealed.
>   If you behave optimally, what is the probability that you will win one of the valuable prizes?"

Has anyone encountered this before? Is there a **procedure/formula** for working it out? And can we generalize the formula (say for $n$ doors, $r$ prizes etc.)?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can there be generalization of Monty Hall Problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346613/can-there-be-generalization-of-monty-hall-problem)

Comment: Also see [Monty hall problem extended.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/608957/139123)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have $n$ doors and $1\le k<n-1$ prizes. You're allowed to pick one door, and after another door has been opened (with no prize), you can switch to another door. In this case, the initial probability of winning is $p_0=k/n$. The probability of winning if you switch can be computed as follows:
\begin{align}
p_{1}&=\frac{k-1}{n-2}\times p_0+\frac{k}{n-2}\times (1-p_0) \\
&=\frac{k(k-1)}{n(n-2)}+\frac{k(n-k)}{n(n-2)} \\
&=\frac{k(n-1)}{n(n-2)}.
\end{align}
It is always profitable to switch because
$$
\frac{k(n-1)}{n(n-2)}>\frac{k}{n}=p_0.
$$

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thanks for your help.